# How to fix "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'" in a Dataflow pipeline reading from PubSub and writing to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create a streaming pipeline with Dataflow that reads messages from a PubSub topic and writes them to a BigQuery table. I don't want to use any template. For the moment I just want to create a pipeline in a Python3 script executed from a Google VM Instance to carry out this simple process without any transformation of the data that arrives from Pubsub (the structure of the messages is what the table expects).

The messages published in the PubSub topic come as follows:

```
data = '{"A":1, "B":"Hey", "C":"You"}'
message = data.encode('utf-8')
```

This is the function that I'm using for the pipeline:

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args = None, streaming = True, 
save_main_session = True)
parse_table_schema_from_json(json.dumps(json.load(open("schema.json"))))

# table_schema = ["fields" :[{"type":"INTEGER", "name":"A", 
# "mode":"REQUIRED"},{"type":"STRING", "name":"B", "mode":"NULLABLE"}, 
# {"type":"STRING", "name":"C", "mode":"NULLABLE"}]]


with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    # Read the pubsub topic and write the menssage into a bigquery table

    message = ( p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic="projects/real- 
                    demand/topics/Test_API", subscription=None)
                  | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table = '$Table', dataset = 
                    '$Dataset', project = '$Project', schema = 
                    table_schema)
               )
```

I have the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: It looks like you're encoding your message data with 'uft-8', did you mean to use 'utf-8'?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I mean to use 'utf-8'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing in a `string` and not `JSON`. You would need to parse the input string as json as below

```
def parse_pubsub(line):
    import json
    record = json.loads(line)
    return (record['A']), (record['B']), (record['C'])
```

and in your pipeline you would have to do something like this

```
  lines = ( p | beam.io.ReadStringsFromPubSub(known_args.input_topic)
                | beam.Map(parse_pubsub)
                | beam.Map(lambda (a_bq, b_bq, c_bq): {'A': a_bq, 'B': b_bq, 'C': c_bq})
                | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    known_args.output_table,
                    schema=' A:STRING, B:STRING, C:STRING',
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            )
```

Comment: I don't know for what reason I'm having the next syntax error at the open parentheses of the argument of the lambda expression:

 File "Pipeline.py", line 36

    | beam.Map(lambda (a_bq, b_bq, c_bq): {'A': a_bq, 'B': b_bq, 'C': c_bq})
                      
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thanks! Finally my code is working with a list that has the values from the JSON message --[record['A'], record['B'], record['C']]--- as the output from "parse_pubsub" and using " the 3th phase of the pipeline this:--| 'TransformToJsonStructure' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {'A': x[0], 'B': x[1], 'C': x[2]})--

Comment: Good to know it worked out. Do accept the answer if that helped